# How to refresh all firebase data on swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I refresh all data on firebase on swift . What I'm trying to do is in another view controller my points are being updated when I return back to my main view controller where the points are displayed the points do not get updated until I close the app and open it again . So I was wondering if anyone knew a refresh function for firebase where I could refresh it on pull down or something like that

Comment: Create a reference for the user whose values you'd like to update and use `updateChildValues.`

Comment: I'm quite new to iOS development , could you explain with an example if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
let reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/{put id here}")

reference.updateChildValues([
    "values": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3",

    ]
])
```

When you go back to your mainViewController, you could use a delegate like viewWillAppear() to force an update of the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example (it was too long to put in a comment):

```
let ref = 
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/90384m590v834dfgok34")

ref.updateChildValues([
"values": [
    "test3",
    "test4"
]
])
```

Comment: Hey @LiamHealy  there's been a slight issue , I tried out implementing the above method as you said . And now the points doesn't even load on the screen from firebase , the code exists to display the points from firebase on a label . And now it doesn't even load. I tried going back to the previous code yet there hasn't been any change . Would you help me out ?